# Custom joomla template navbar issue

Tags: joomla-3.6

I am totally new to this kinda stuff but i have got this index.php([index.php](https://pastebin.com/SWFXBJVh)) and this template.Details.xml([templateDetails.xml](https://pastebin.com/0zcDmWzW)). But the navigation bar looks completely different than this [image]. It now looks like this [image]. How do I tell Joomla! that I want to have the bootstrap styling and not the default links.

Comment: Rather than dropping links to your scripts and volunteers needing to chase them down, you can edit your question to copy-paste the scripts into formatted code blocks here.  This is also preferable to prevent vital question details existing only outside of JSE.

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla backend, go to the Menu module, click on the "Advanced" tab and you will see a field called "Module Class Suffix" (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863558/bootstrap-3-navbar-in-joomla-3)).

In there, add the following:

```
navbar-nav
```

Note that there is a space before it. This is valid for Bootstrap 3. For Boostrap 4 please see the Bootstrap documntation. I will most probably need to do something similar for each menu entry, e.g.. adding " nav" to the entry item as well.

Alternatively, you could override the mod_menu layout. The easiest is to copy the file from "modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php" to "templates//html/mod_menu/default.php". Now you can alter the file in your template folder as you like and add the necessary classes. Here is one, that I did a couple of months ago to work with bootstrap 4. You will probably need to adjust it to your needs.

```
 <?php


defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Note. It is important to remove spaces between elements.
?>
<?php // The menu class is deprecated. Use nav instead. ?>
<ul class="menu<?php echo $class_sfx;?>"<?php
    $tag = '';

    if ($params->get('tag_id') != null)
    {
        $tag = $params->get('tag_id') . '';
        echo ' id="' . $tag . '"';
    }
?>>
<?php
foreach ($list as $i => &$item)
{
    $class = 'nav-item item-' . $item->id;

    if (($item->id == $active_id) OR ($item->type == 'alias' AND $item->params->get('aliasoptions') == $active_id))
    {
        $class .= ' current';
    }

    if (in_array($item->id, $path))
    {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif ($item->type == 'alias')
    {
        $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');

        if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1])
        {
            $class .= ' active';
        }
        elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path))
        {
            $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
        }
    }

    if ($item->type == 'separator')
    {
        $class .= ' dropdown-divider';
    }

    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        $class .= ' deeper';
    }

    if ($item->parent)
    {
        $class .= ' parent dropdown';
    }

    if (!empty($class))
    {
        $class = ' class="' . trim($class) . '"';
    }

    echo '<li' . $class . '>';
    $item->anchor_css = 'nav-link' . $item->anchor_css;
    if($item->level > $params->get('startLevel')) {
        $item->anchor_css = 'dropdown-item';
    }

    // The next item is deeper.
    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        $item->anchor_css .= ' dropdown-toggle';
        $item->data = 'data-toggle="dropdown"';
    }

    // Render the menu item.
    switch ($item->type) :
        case 'separator':
        case 'url':
        case 'component':
        case 'heading':
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' . $item->type);
            break;

        default:
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
            break;
    endswitch;

    // The next item is deeper.
    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        echo '<ul class="nav-child unstyled dropdown-menu">';
    }
    elseif ($item->shallower)
    {
        // The next item is shallower.
        echo '</li>';
        echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
    }
    else
    {
        // The next item is on the same level.
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?></ul>
```